# The use of "so" instead of "thus" in reported speech

Tags: grammar

Is it common for native speakers to use the adverb "so" instead of "thus" in reported structures? For example:

Alan said," The chemist diluted the syrup, **thus** it lost its effectiveness."

Alan said that the chemist had diluted the syrup, **so** it lost its effectiveness.

Comment: @John l know that "thus" is more formal, but  I am asking about the frequency of "so" and " thus" in reported speech.

Comment: In that case I think so is more common now, I rarely hear thus or see it in writing but others' mileage may vary. Also, I can't think of any situations where "thus" can be used that you couldn't substitute "so", but the same is not true the other way around: consider the sentence "I'm so sick today I can't even get out of bed."

Comment: This is the conjunction usage of 'so'. Dictionaries tend perversely to label the near-parallel usage of 'thus' that of an 'adverb'.  Collins is braver and classes it not as an adverb but as a 'sentence connector' synonymous with 'therefore' / 'for this reason'. The example they give is of the form " The chemist diluted the syrup. Thus it lost its effectiveness." I'd say at least a semicolon is warranted. // I'd agree that 'thus' is nowhere near as common as 'so' in this type of usage, and sounds far more formal.

Comment: I second the semicolon before 'thus' and, in American English, before 'so' as well.  'So' is still labeled as nothing more than adverb by MW and, in contrast to the UK, is not taught as a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

For sure it's at least 85% more common to say *"so"* instead of *"thus"* in the US even when we write.

(The Googling squad shall confirm it !)

Comment: You are right. I have the same opinion that "thus" is more stilted and formal in such a structure.